# HttpWorkerRequest.GetPreloadedEntityBody on IIS7 Intergated mode

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, httphandler

I'm trying to build a HttpHandler (.NET Framework 4) that will handle the upload of large files.
The idea is to get a hold of the [HttpWorkerRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpworkerrequest.aspx) and read the body-stream. I use the *HttpWorkerRequest.[GetPreloadedEntityBody](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpworkerrequest.getpreloadedentitybody.aspx)* to retrieve the first chunk of the HTTP body that was received.

Here is how I get the pre-loaded entity :

```
IServiceProvider provider = (IServiceProvider)context;
HttpWorkerRequest wr = (HttpWorkerRequest)provider.GetService(typeof(HttpWorkerRequest));
byte[] entityBodyBytes = wr.GetPreloadedEntityBody();
```

This works well when I run my website under my local IIS (5.1 under windows xp) or the Visual Studio Web Server, but when I run it under IIS 7 (integrated mode), the *GetPreloadedEntityBody* method constantly returns an empty byte array.

Any idea on why the returned byte array of the *GetPreloadedEntityBody* method is empty on IIS 7 ?

Comment: I had exactly the same problem, I've found a solution by switching IIS 7 to classic mode

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert on this, but I think it's because none of the body has loaded by the time you ask.  Try checking if GetPreloadedEntityBodyLength() > 0 before calling GetPreloadedEntityBody().  If it is zero then you'll have to jump right into your file reading loop.